# Redirect user on login if items in cart using Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

When a user logs in successfully, I would like to check the contents of their cart (I'm using darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart) and if they have items in their cart, proceed to my checkout page.

I tried adding this under Http/Middleware/RedirectifAuthenticated.php but no luck (just goes to the homepage).

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        //return redirect('/');
        if( \Cart::getTotalQuantity() > 0 ) {
            return redirect('/checkout');
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended('/');
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Using the default LoginContoller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
class LoginController extends Controller
{
  use AuthenticatesUsers;
  /**
   * Where to redirect users after login.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $redirectTo = '/home';        
   /**
   * Create a new controller instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it using that class to do the redirect to the homepage? Maybe put a dd(\Cart::getTotalQuantity()); in the ->check() if statement and see what the output is so you can determine if it's recognising their cart.

Answer (score 0):

My take is that the Cart Class doesnt know the user..

Why do it in the middleware? Do you want to do that check on every request?

If not: There should be exactly one login route and in the corresponding Controller / callback use these lines.

Comment: I'm using the latest authentication for Laravel 5.3 and the only route for login, logout, etc is Route::auth();   I'm using the default LoginController (which I'll add as an edit above).